# How to force a bigger tikzpicture

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to plot some points with tikzpicture environment.
I have the folowing code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis x line=center,
axis y line=center,
grid=both,
xtick={-5,-3,...,40},
ytick={-5,-4,...,40},
xlabel={$x$},
ylabel={$y$},
xlabel style={below right},
ylabel style={above left},
xmin=-5.5,
xmax=5.5,
ymin=-5.5,
ymax=5.5]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And this is what I get:
[image]

It is fine, but, if I add more x points, for example, setting

```
xmax=40,
```

It is imposible to see nothing there

[image]

Is there any way to make x axis larger?

Edit: I'm editing this post to provide a MWE.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis x line=center,
        axis y line=center,
        grid=both,
        xtick={-5,-3,...,40},
        ytick={-5,-4,...,40},
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        xlabel style={below right},
        ylabel style={above left},
        xmin=-5.5,
        xmax = 5.5,
        %xmax=40,
        ymin=-5.5,
        ymax=5.5]
        \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Could you please provide a complete MWE (Minimal Working Example) of your full code?

Comment: You're not setting a scale or a font size in that example, which isn't going to help.

Comment: Yes, I've edited the post to provide a MWE, it's a really simple document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm posting the solution here

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis x line=center,
axis y line=center,
grid=both,
xtick={-5,-3,...,40},
ytick={-5,-4,...,40},
xlabel={$x$},
ylabel={$y$},
xlabel style={below right},
ylabel style={above left},
xmin=-5.5,
%xmax = 5.5,
xmax=40,
ymin=-5.5,
ymax=5.5,
xscale=2]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Just add

> xscale=2

to you axis environment.